# Numbering sequential numbers in a column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to give a number to the value based on value in above row such that when the sequence breaks, it should again start from 1 otherwise should keep on increment the number.

The query is :

```
select'30300001' as lst union all
select'30300002' union all
select'30300003' union all
select'30300004' union all
select'30300001' union all
select'30300006' union all
select'30300007' union all
select'30300008' union all
select'30300009'
```

And the output I want to be as:

```
select'30300001' as lst,1 as rnk union all
select'30300002',2 union all
select'30300003',3 union all
select'30300004',4 union all
select'30300001',1 union all
select'30300006',1 union all
select'30300007',2 union all
select'30300008',3 union all
select'30300009',4
```

I tried it with row_number and rank functions but could not get the required output. How can I get the desired result?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh Its SQL Server 2008

Comment: SQL tables and result sets represent *unordered* sets.  You need a column to specify the ordering.  How is the order of the rows defined?

Comment: The Order I have listed is based on ordering by ID column which I have not  taken in this query as its just a smallest snippet to ask my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `orderingid` (of some sort), then you can use the difference between your column and a column with a sequence.  This identifies a group, which can then be used with other window functions:

```
select q.*,
       row_number() over (partition by grp order by orderingid)
from (select q.*,
             (lst - row_number() over (order by orderingid)) as grp
      from query q
     ) q;
```

Note:  this assumes that `lst` is actually a number or a value readily converted to a number.

Comment: Running this query is giving the output as : [link](http://i.imgur.com/Rm2rgju.jpg) which is disturbing the order I wanted and sorting on ID gives : [link](http://i.imgur.com/xElppoM.png) which is clearly not what I want.

Comment: @HemantSisodia . . Just add an `order by` to put it in the order you want.

Comment: Ordering by ID gives the output I already shown in the second link in my previous comment. Its giving value as 5 on row with ID 6 instead of resetting it to 1 and then 2 and so on. This is the query with my changes: select q.*,
       row_number() over (partition by grp order by ID)
from (select q.*,
             (lst - row_number() over (order by ID)) as grp
      from query q
     ) q order by id      which is giving the output as [link](https://i.imgur.com/xElppoM.png) which is wrong.

Comment: `order by orderingid`.

Comment: I have that orderingid as ID only.